# Google App Engine /_ah/health

Tags: google-app-engine

I've set up my Node.js app to log any request that returns 404. Like this:

```
console.error("404: " + req.url);
```

Now when debugging other issue, I found out that my log is flooded with these:

```
404: /_ah/health
404: /_ah/health
404: /_ah/health
```

There are countless number of them and they aren't even 1ms apart.

What are they? Who sent them? Is it from GAE? Some sort of health check polling or something? Should I serve that URL? What should I serve in that URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serve anything that returns a 200 response.  It is health check polling.  BTW, you can turn that off:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/how-instances-are-managed

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks

Comment: I don't understand your answer here. The question says he's logging 404s, so are you telling us to just never have 404s? Otherwise you cannot use the built-in health checks?

Comment: Correct.  Make sure a request to `/_ah/health` returns a 200 response.  That is a test to make sure the app is running (healthy).

Comment: The docs also say 404 is treated as 'healthy' so this shouldn't be spamming the logs. Sounds like an App Engine bug

Comment: For me these logs are at info level. I won't say that it's a bug. Also, I agree that 404 is treated as a health response as per the doc. If the app is not deployed or is not running, I expect to receive 5xx response.

Answer (score 0):

For example when using nodejs with express you can do something like:

```
app.get('/_ah/health', function(req, res) {
  res.type('text').send('ok');
});
```